# What's MessageTypeId in OCPP request payload

Tags: ocpp

In OCPP 1.6, the client (Charging Station) sends a CALL (similar to request in HTTP) to server (Charging Station Management Systems). All CALLs have a strict structure of 4 elements:

- MessageTypeId (integer)
- UniqueId (UUID, string)
- Action (string)
- Payload (JSON object containing the arguments relevant to the
  Action.)

I have gone through the documentation but I cannot find `MessageTypeId`. So I want to know whether it is just a random number?

Example request payload:

```
[
  2,// <----- I want to know, where I can find this. 
  "a7caa7a1-c309-43bd-af3f-b5c1c4f9657e", 
  "Authorize",
  {
    "idTag": "${req.body.idTag}"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MessageTypeId` Defines the type of Message, whether it is `Call`, `CallResult` or `CallError`:

```
MessageType | MessageTypeId | Direction

CALL        |       2       | Client-to-Server

CALLRESULT  |       3       | Server-to-Client

CALLERROR   |       4       | Server-to-Client
```

You can read more on page 9 of [This document](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/59590/) .

Comment: Thanks a lot for the documentation. Can you provide any other useful documentation?

Comment: @Mr.Gandhi No problem. I'm not so familair with ocpp, but the messageTypeId is also stated at page 9 of : https://smartcharge.com.br/artigos/ocpp/OCPP-2.0_part4_ocpp-j-specification.pdf and here is a list of other related docs: https://smartcharge.com.br/artigos/ocpp/ (the 6 links under `Manual OCPP 2.0` section. they are in english.). (you can always find these 2 docs by googling `messagetypeid ocpp`.)

Answer (score 0):

The OCA is authorized site for getting every single documented information for EV related software like different protocol of OCPP.
Link is as below from which you can download all documentation which contains,

- Schema of request and response
- Defination
- Connection details
- Structure of Messaging
- Details of when to you which request and its meaning

https://www.openchargealliance.org/downloads/

More over, for your query, once you downloaded there is a document named "ocpp-j-1.6-specification" on where page 10 contains official details

[Message type OCPP 1.6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xl3Fl.png) from OCPP 1.6 but from this its not means that CALL will be always from client to server. some request CALL are also there which can be initiated from CSMS(Charging station management system) to CS(Charging station)

Thus below is another documented image for same purpose with newer version of ocpp 2.0.1
[Message type OCPP 2.0.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQeLY.png) In here its clearly saying that the request will contains CALL to identifying its a request irrespective of source of generation (Either from CSMS or from CS)